# Из PHP - в JavaScript: выполнение $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Tags: javascript, php

Вот есть скрипт на php:

```
<?php
echo 'http://counter.yadro.ru/logo;'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'?29.1';
?>
```

Как то же самое реализовать на javascript'е?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('http://counter.yadro.ru/logo;' + window.location.host + '?29.1');
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```